# PHP Soap Dont Accept Dynamic Variables

Tags: php, variables, soap

I need to get some data using a web service in PHP. The first function I run returns an id. If I give this id as a variable to the second function (I wrote this function clearly below), it returns null. But if I write statically, the data comes. What could be the problem?

```
    $tc = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
    $bireyId = firstFunc($tc); //Get user uniqId

    // second function codes
    $client = new SoapClient("URL/Service.asmx?WSDL");
  try{
    $authHeader = array(
      "Username" => "Username",
      "Password" => "Password"
    );
    $requestData = array(
     "InstructorId" => $bireyId
    );
    $header = new SoapHeader("http://tempuri.org/","AuthHeader",$authHeader,false);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
    $result = $client->GetInstructorCourses($requestData); 
        print_r($result);
  }catch (Exception $ex){
    return $ex->faultstring;
  }
```

If I manually write 1111 to the InstructorId value, the data comes. But if I write as above, the data is not coming.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I found out what the problem is. The first function sends me xml data, not a string value. I solved the problem when I shredded this data